# NServiceBus 5 and 6 compatibility

Tags: .net, nservicebus, nservicebus5, nservicebus6

Can an NserviceBus 6 endpoint send a message to an NServiceBus bus 5 endpoint?

I have two .Net projects, one defines an endpoint in version 6 and sends a message to an endpoint defined in version 5. The handler in version 5 isn't picking up the message so I cannot get those endpoints to talk to each other. Is this because they are not compatible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NServiceBus is backwards compatible at least down to version 4 which means endpoints running versions 4 and 7 can talk to each other. It is technically possible to talk to endpoints running even older versions but these versions only supported MSMQ as a message transport. If an endpoint does not pick a message up from the queue that might indicated that it is either bound to a different queue or not running.